# Setting up email notifications on cruise control

Tags: cruisecontrol

I've just started using cruisecontrol and have setup all the neccessary dependencies like jdk and now i'm running the example project under Projects in the cruisecontrol folder,  i would like to sent out emails to myself everytime it runs but when i read through the documentation it tells me that i should configure the emails under the config.xml file which i did like

> ```
> <property name="buildmaster.email"  value="email@example.co.za"/>
>   <property name="buildmaster.name"  value="Donald Mailula Testing"/>
> ```

outsite the project attribute, i would like to know if i'm required to add additional configurations or not if so please help me with get to the right direction. and i have tried several times to changes my intervals under the xml files to shorten the time which it runs but it doesnt change but runs after every 5 min. I'm using CC 2.8.4 and still checking out how it works before i implement it on the server.

Thank you in advance.

NB: I've neva used any integration tool before.

D~

This is how my config file looks like at the moment.

> ```
>  <publishers>
>    <email returnaddress="email@gmail.com"
>        mailhost="smtp.gmail.com" 
>        password="secretpassword"
>        username="email@gmail.com"
>
>                <always address="dmailula@example.com"/>
>     </email>
> </publishers>
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to set up the mail notifications like ,

```
< publishers>

< email from="fromaddress" mailhost="host address"
         mailhostPassword="password" mailhostUsername="username" 
         includeDetails="true">

     <users>
         <user name="name" address="to address"
             group="NotifyGroup" />
     </users>
     <groups>
         <group name="NotifyGroup" notification="failed" />
     </groups>
< /email>
</publishers>
```

Refernce: http://www.stevetrefethen.com/blog/ConfiguringemailnotificationsforCruiseControlNET.aspx

Comment: Hi Mahesh,

I have tried to put in the code you posted but it complains that it doesnt find the users plugin when i define it i get an classname error message, i'm using the surgeforge cruisecontrol and i cant find the classname for users, i thought it was a child element for publishers but it seems like it doesnt get it. please help me if i have to define the classname somewhere or not.

Comment: did you add the users in Users.config.

Comment: I've created a txt file called Users.config and added a user like donald:example@email.com

Comment: I dont get any error message it just doesnt sent out emails..:(

Comment: if you add mailhost as smtp.gmail.com,gmail server requires authentication. How to specify SSL enabled. So its better to use any local mail server

Comment: I've added our local mailhost information but it doesnt do anything, no errors and it doesnt sent out any mail, i want it to always sent out emails everytym it builds just to see if the email is working.

Comment: Thanks Mahesh for helping me out, i found out that the problem was that it wont sent mails everytime the build file runs and there are no new builds created, meaning i have to change the file before it can actually sent out a mail. my bad!!

Comment: I think the question was about the java based http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net and not cruisecontrol.net

Comment: How to send mail example for Java CruiseControl 2.8.4. http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/gettingstartedsourcedist.html