# CruiseControlException: Unknown plugin for: <users>

Tags: cruisecontrol

I'm trying to set up some group email notifications in Cruise Control, and I have been following the pattern of many examples I've found:

```
<htmlemail mailhost="${mail.host}" subjectprefix="${mail.subject.prefix}" returnaddress="${mail.address.return}"
                    buildresultsurl="${build.url}/${project.name}" css="${css.location}" xsldir="${xsl.dir}"
                    xslfilelist="header.xsl,buildresults.xsl" returnname="${return.name}" skipusers="false" spamwhilebroken="false"
                    username="${cc.mail.username}" password="${cc.mail.password}" usessl="true" mailport="465" >
    <users>
        <user name="svnUser" group="buildmaster" address="${mail.address.buildmanager}"/>
    </users>
    <groups>
        <group name="buildmaster" >
            <notifications>
                <notificationType>Always</notificationType>
            </notifications>
        </group>                
    </groups>       
</htmlemail>
```

When I start CC, I get the following exception:

```
....
Caused by: net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.CruiseControlException: Unknown plugin for: <users>
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.ProjectXMLHelper.configurePlugin(ProjectXMLHelper.java:106)
....
```

I think someone had the same issue last year, but there was no solution to the  error:

[Setting up email notifications on cruise control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869468/setting-up-email-notifications-on-cruise-control)

This seems like such a simple thing to do so does anyone have any insight into why this exception is happening?

Comment: the other answer is about cruisecontrol.net which is NOT http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/, which you seem to be using

Comment: It's not working because users and groups don't exist in the version of CruiseControl you're using. See this page for an example of sending mail : http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/gettingstartedsourcedist.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the map child elements of [`<email />`](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#email)

like:

```
<map alias="mag82" adress="mail@test.com"/>
```

where alias is the svn user name.